# Is there a more expressive way of executing SQL query using Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4

I currently have this code:

```
  // Construct query
  QString const statement = QString("drop database if exists %1")
                                    .arg(databaseName_);

  QSqlQuery query(db);
  query.exec(statement);
```

Is there a better way to code than the above?

Specifically, I dont like how I use `QString` for SQL statement. It'd be nice if Qt has some class so that I could do something like:

```
  // Construct query
  QSomeClass statement = "drop database if exists %1";
  statement.setArg(1, databaseName_); // Replace all %1 in the original string.

  QSqlQuery query(db);
  query.exec(statement);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are basically describing query placeholders:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("INSERT INTO person (id, forename, surname) "
              "VALUES (:id, :forename, :surname)");
query.bindValue(":id", 1001);
query.bindValue(":forename", "Bart");
query.bindValue(":surname", "Simpson");
query.exec();
```

The only difference between the code snipped above and QSomeClass you described is the fact that you have to specify database when creating the query.